# displaying facebook albums on website

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, facebook

hi i'm trying to display facebook albums of a page onto my website.

i found this: http://codepen.io/dejanstojanovic/pen/QjwLZp and this does pretty much what I want to accomplish.

```
$(".fb-album-container").FacebookAlbumBrowser({
account: "natgeo",
accessToken: "775908159169504|cYEIsh0rs25OQQC8Ex2hXyCOut4",
```

my only concern is: are the account and the accessToken ok to out in the open like that? are there any security issues with it? and if so, how would I go upon hiding them while still accomplishing the script?

it'll be a wordpress site so maybe some workaround with php if necessary?

thanks.

Comment: No, that is of course not o.k. Access tokens should never be exposed in client-side code. You should do this server-side. That has the added advantage that you can implement some form of caching, so that not every request to your site means a request to the FB API as well (with which you would run into the rate limits pretty quickly anyway.)

Comment: @CBroe hi sorry i'm a little new to these api stuff and pretty much anything outside html and css. how would i go upon making something like this server side? if you could point me in the right direction of what i'm searching for that would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Here's a PHP script that works for me https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will use the client token from Facebook Developers. This token can be visible.

The account is the slug of the FB page, that is a public name. In your example:
http://facebook.de/natgeo

To create this token you must log-in to [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com), create an App assign this app to your website and at the Settings > Advanced > Security there is the Client Token you can use for your application.

Comment: thanks. i went ahead and created my own accesstoken for this and it does work as desired. you're saying that since the token is facebook anyway it's ok to be visible - to pretty much use the example as is without major changes?

Comment: It is ok as long as you use the client-side token from your facebook application, other tokens will cause security issues. Client-side means that this token is for javascript.

Comment: No, it is not o.k. to expose _your_ user access token in client-side code to others either. If you use access tokens client-side at all, than it should be that of the _current_ app user (meaning, you would need to make site visitors login to your app first, before they can see the album photos.)

Comment: But I can - as an evil person - use this token and get most of the users data for my own purpose. With the application token this is bound to an url ... or did I missunderstand something?